# Solve function giving only complex answers

Tags: equation-solving, complex

The code is supposed to move the center of a circle of radius "d" incrementally *on* a function (the one in the first line), then solve for the two intercepts and repeat. I noticed that it gave two complex coordinates for every point as well (not really sure why, Id be glad if someone could explain), but I ignored it. However, as soon as the program reaches around halfway through the domain (x0 = 320), it outputs *only* complex answers, but logically, the circle should still intercept the function twice. What's going on?

```
y[x_] := (x Tan[Theta]) - ((10*(x^2))/(2*(v^2)*((Cos[Theta])^2)))
a = Table[sol := Solve[y1 == y[x1] &&
                       d == EuclideanDistance[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}], {x1, y1}];
z = N[sol //. {x0 -> i, v -> 80, Theta -> Pi/4, d -> 0.8255, y0 -> y[x0]}], {i, 0, 640, 2}]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some context?  In particular, why do you expect real solutions to exist for all $x_0, y_0$?  Right now it just looks like the system$$y_1 = x_1 - \alpha x_1^2 \\(x_1-x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2 = d^2,$$which can be reduced to a fourth-order real polynomial in $x_1$.  It's not surprising that depending on the values of the coefficients of this polynomial, there can be four, two, or zero real roots.

Comment: You can call `Solve[eq,vars,domain]` with `Reals` as a third argument to limit the solution domain to strictly real solutions. Also you can make solving much faster by applying your replacement rules before solving. You also only need to solve once and then you can reuse the general solution obtained by `Solve`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert As he explained, he's basically moving the center of a circle along a curve. Geometrically, you'd expect the circle to intersect the curve at least twice, provided the curve does not have discontinuities

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I edited the question to show that I'm only looking at the domain 0<x0<640, but yes as Mathe172 says, geometrically it makes sense.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Edit- Sorry spoke too soon, I tried the Reals argument but evaluation is taking way too long now, even though after abortion, the program seems to have moved on.

Comment: @AgentWowza Look at my answer to see an example how to put the `Reals` argument to use without the long waiting time. The intermediate answers you get, when you paste the code into Mathematica and evaluate it are also helpful for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the general solution returned by `Solve` doesn't return all/any solutions when $y'(x)=0$. You can circumvent this by inserting the values first and solving afterwards, this ensures that `Solve` sees the special case and finds all solutions:

```
y[x_] := (x Tan[Theta]) - ((10*(x^2))/(2*(v^2)*((Cos[Theta])^2))) 
a = Table[
  sol = Solve[
    (y1 == y[x1] && d == EuclideanDistance[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}])
     //. {x0 -> i, v -> 80, Theta -> Pi/4, d -> 0.8255, y0 -> y[x0]},
    {x1, y1}
    ];
  z = N[sol],
  {i, 320, 640, 1}
  ]
```

Comment: I see it's not returning complex values anymore, thanks! However, should it not return duplicated values, as you have not SetDelayed sol (pretty new to mathematica you see)? Why doesn't it?

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487) help?

Comment: Got it, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

I tried to take your code and simplify it a bit to make things easier to understand and faster:

```
y[x_] = (x Tan[theta]) - ((10*(x^2))/(2*(v^2)*((Cos[theta])^2)))
initialconditions = {x0 -> i, v -> 80, theta -> Pi/4, d -> Rationalize[0.8255], y0 -> y[x0]}
eqs = y1 == y[x1] && d^2 == SquaredEuclideanDistance[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}]
sol = Solve[eqs //. initialconditions, {x1, y1}, Reals]
a = Transpose@Table[ N[{x1, y1} /. sol], {i, 320, 640, 1}];
ListPlot[a]
```

[image: Plot of two near coincident trajectories]

## Explanation

I'll go through every line to explain what and why i changed it:

```
y[x_] = (x Tan[theta]) - ((10*(x^2))/(2*(v^2)*((Cos[theta])^2)))
```

For the definition of `y` a `=` (`Set`) instead of `:=` (`SetDelayed`) suffices, since the right hand expression will always evaluate to the same thing, we just want classic function behaviour here. Also i put `theta` in lowercase since upper case symbols are usually reserved for functions.

```
initialconditions = {x0 -> i, v -> 80, theta -> Pi/4, d -> Rationalize[0.8255], y0 -> y[x0]}
```

We can put the replacement rules in a named expression for better readability and put `Rationalize` around the value of `d` in case we are interested in exact solutions.

```
eqs = y1 == y[x1] && d^2 == SquaredEuclideanDistance[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}]
```

Distance constraints are usually better (read easier to solve for mathematica and give simple solutions) formulated in terms of squared distance, since we can get rid of a square root this way without changing the meaning of our constraint.

```
sol = Solve[eqs //. initialconditions, {x1, y1}, Reals]
```

We can now compute the general solution outside the loop (which means we only need to compute it once), but with the initial conditions already substituted (which means `Solve` will give us a result *much* quicker). Also we used the `Reals` domain argument to constrain the solution set, which gives us two real solution for each `i`.

```
a = Transpose@Table[ N[{x1, y1} /. sol], {i, 320, 640, 1}];
```

We let `Table` take our general solution and let it go through every `i` value, which now all reduce to numerical values. The `Transpose` is there to bring it in a form of two lists of points, suitable to be displayed by `ListPlot`.

Comment: This really helps streamline the process, thanks!